# preg_replace img src, width, height stack overflow

Tags: php, html

This's my codes:

```
$content = '<p><img src="http://localhost/contents/uploads/sdadaasa.jpg" width="1500" height="900"></p>';
$content = preg_replace('/<p><img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', "<p class=\"the-image\"><img class=\"lazy-load\" src=\"$1\" width=\"\" height=\"\"/></p>", $content);
return $content;
```

My code is add a class for `<p>` tag and `<img>` tag.

Now i want to also get the width and height from `$content` because my code is removing the width and height attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To parser HTML it's better to use any library as, for example, DomDocument

```
$content = '<p><img src="http://localhost/contents/uploads/sdadaasa.jpg" width="1500" height="900"></p>';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$p = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
$p->setAttribute('class', 'the-image');
$img = $p->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
$img->setAttribute('class', 'lazy-load');
echo $dom->saveHTML($p); 
// <p class="the-image"><img src="http://localhost/contents/uploads/sdadaasa.jpg" width="1500" height="900" class="lazy-load"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think using preg_replace will be more useful for me because the content is a post for a blog so the content maybe has many tags and images, Hope you understand me.

Comment: for many tags you can do foreach and select needed one by content ro use xpath

Comment: Can you give me an example for this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is a regex going to do better if there are multiple images. The example string does not leave much room for making out different images.